# Change specific row template after occurence

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I have this kendo grid that I add columns dynamically to it in something like this:

```
                     obj = {
                        field: field,
                        title: title,
                        editor: transactionDocumentTextEditor,
                        format: format,
                        headerTemplate: headerTemplate,
                        width: 40,
                        template: " <div class='documentBtn'><img src='../Images/document-disabled-icon.svg' border='0'></div> "
                    };
```

then later after adding all the columns I add them to the kendogrid columns,
the I made in editor this specific column to be clickable as :

```
            function transactionDocumentTextEditor(container, options) {
            if (options != null) {
                var model = options.model;
                var ItemTypesItemTypeID = model.ItemTypesItemTypeID;

                var disabled = "";
                if ((ItemTypesItemTypeID == 1) || (ItemTypesItemTypeID == 4) || (ItemTypesItemTypeID == 2))
                    disabled = " disabled ";

                if (ItemTypesItemTypeID != "" && (ItemTypesItemTypeID == 3)) {
                    OpenDocumentUpload("ReceiveDocumentUpload.aspx?TransType=Stock", container);
                    currentContainer = container;
                    currentOptions = options;
                }
            }
        }

        function OpenDocumentUpload(path) {
            var windowObj = parent.radopen("" + localStorage.controlsPath.toString() + "/Common/" + path, 'UserListDialog100', '300px', '300px');
            windowObj.add_beforeClose(OnClientClose_DocumentWindow);
            return true;
        }

        function OnClientClose_DocumentWindow(sender, args) {
            var documentId;
            if (sender.documentId != null) {
                documentId = sender.documentId;
                transactionDocumentTextEditorImage(currentContainer, documentId);

            }

        }

        function transactionDocumentTextEditorImage(container, documentId) {
            $("<div class='documentBtnEnabled'><input id='doc_ " + documentId + "' data-bind='value: " + documentId + "></div>")
                .replaceAll(container)
        }
```

now after using this editor I can add document and after closing the page and back to the grid, I call transactionDocumentTextEditorImage() so I can change the color of the picture to another picture that I have called in CSS, and it changes successfully.
But the problem is when I add another column to the kendo-grid, the template of the specific row that I changed the picture goes back to the default template that was before editing it, I searched about that issue but haven't found anything that specific, but I guess it should be something as an if condition in template ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have done some workaround and now it works,
I changed in OnClientClose_DocumentWindow :

```
            function OnClientClose_DocumentWindow(sender, args) {
            var documentId;
            if (sender.documentId != null) {
                documentId = sender.documentId;
                $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.getByUid(currentOptions.model.uid).transactionDocument = documentId;
                transactionDocumentTextEditorImage(currentContainer,documentId);
            }

        }
```

then I changed template to  :

```
obj = {
                        field: field,
                        title: title,
                        editor: editor,
                        format: format,
                        headerTemplate: headerTemplate,
                        width: 40,
                        template: "#if( data.transactionDocument == null || data.transactionDocument == ''){# #= GetTemp() # #} else {#<div class='documentBtnEnabled'></div>#}#"
                    };
```

I will keep the question just in case someone needs it